# Запуск тест-сьютов юнит-тестов в PyCharm

Tags: python, selenium, юнит-тесты, pycharm, python-unittest

Есть следующий файл:
SomeTest1.py

```
__author__ = 'vbilohorodskyi'

import unittest
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common import keys


class InitDriverTest(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()

    print("=========================================================")

    #initializing browser and verifying if the selected URL is accessible and has correct content by key values
    def testInit_driver_and_url(self):
        driver = self.driver
        driver.get("somesite.com")
        assert "Some title" in driver.title

        print("Init driver and url: PASS")

    def tearDown(self):
        self.driver.quit()

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        unittest.main()
```

И есть второй файл с такой же архитектурой, но другим тест-кейсом.

Оба этих файла находятся в одном Python Package, и отдельно запускаются без проблем. Как только пытаюсь запустить все тесты из пакета, наблюдаю ошибку

```
Process finished with exit code 0
Empty test suite.
```

Файл **init.py** для данного пакета пустой.

Пробовал менять конфигурацию Runner'а, игрался с названиями классов и методов(test- вначале и -Test в конце), пробовал разные Regexp'ы в качестве паттерна в конфигурации Runner'а, но ничего не помогло.

Кто-нибудь сталкивался с этой проблемой?
Буду признателен за помощь в настройке запуска тест-сьютов из пекеджа.

Comment: А как вы их запускаете? Отдельная конфигурация run/debug? Или из контекстного меню к файлу или папке?

Answer (score 1):

У меня успешно работает такая конфигурация тестов:

[image: Конфигурация тестов]

Настройки: "All in folder", указана папка (не пакет) с тестами: `tests`. Никаких шаблонов не указано. Рабочая папка — папка всего проекта.

Вот как выглядит папка с тестами:

[image: Папка с тестами]

Все файлы имеют префикс `test_`, все классы унаследованы от `unittest.TestCase` и имеют префикс `Test`.

Версия PyCharm Community Edition 5.0.3.

Кроме этого, у вас в примере с табуляциями беда. `if __name__ == "__main__":` не должен иметь табуляции впереди.

Answer (score 1):

Путём пары попыток выяснилось, что для обработки всех тестов в каталоге есть 2 варианта:

1. все имена файлов с тестами начинать с test_
2. ни одного имени файла не начинать с test_, а в конфигурации в качестве паттерна указать *.py

`__init__.py` не нужен, т.к. вряд ли будем импортировать.

Answer (score 0):

Все тесты запустятся, если следовать правилу - файлы с тестами должны содержать в имени строку «test_», имена классов — начинаться с «Test», а методов — со строки «test_».

Answer (score 0):

[image: Дерево пакета из двух модулей ex01.py & ex02.py]

Содержание выделенного __init__.py (не выделенный __init__.py - пустой):

```
__all__ = ['ex01', 'ex02']
```

Содержание ex01.py:

```
import unittest

class TestCase01(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_003(self):
        self.assertEqual(True, True)
```

Содержание ex02.py:
    import unittest

```
class TestCase02(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_001(self):
        self.assertEqual(True, True)
```

Содержание run_test_package.py:

```
import unittest
from tests_package.ex01 import *
from tests_package.ex02 import *

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Запускаем run_test_package.py и скрипты тестов выполняются.